# if you have one, you have none

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

If you have three, you have three. If you have two, you have two. If you have one, you have none. What is it?

Comment: Lays Potato chips: you can't have just one.

Comment: Backups! One is none!

Comment: Well?  Is there an answer?

Comment: @PeregrineRook There are now 14. What more do you want? :-)

Comment: [Ha](https://xkcd.com/927) [ha](http://blogs.opentext.com/the-great-thing-about-standards-is-there-are-so-many-to-choose-from). Here's a new riddle: if you have one, you have one, but if you have many, you have none. What is it?

Comment: Only one answer really fits though...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This is kind of a play on words, but:

> **Options**
>
>  If you have 3 options, you have 3 options. If you have 2 options you have 2 options. If you have only 1 option, you don't have any options.

Along similar lines, this works too:

> **Choices**
>
>  If you have 3 choices, you have 3 choices. If you have 2 choices you have 2 choices. If you have only 1 choice, you don't have a choice.

Answer (score 51):

If you say the riddle aloud, the answer could be:

> Competitors

Because:

> "one" sounds like "won". If you have 2 or 3 competitors, then you have 2 or 3 competitors. But if you have "won", then you have none.

Answer (score 28):

What about

> Stack Exchange Reputation Score?

If you have three, you have three.

If you have two, you have two,

but if you have one, you have none.

> as it is the default rep score here. If you have 1 rep score **you really have none**.

Comment: well i got 100 just for joining, but hey, that's SE :)

Comment: Cause you've been in the network for a while ;)

Comment: But we all know that, in general,  if you have $n$, then you really have only $n-1$.

Answer (score 27):

It may be

> the number of consecutive consonants at the beginning of the word
> for the numeral.
>
> ```
> THREE
> ↑↑↑     = 3 (three)
> TWO
> ↑↑      = 2 (two)
> ONE
> -       = 0 (zero, i.e., none)
> ```

And so it turns out that, if you have none (or zero), you have one —
which somehow seems appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

It probably isn't, but could be:

> Neighboring cells in Conway's Game of Life

Because

> A cell with two or three live neighbors will be alive in the next iteration, while a cell with only one live neighbor will die.

Answer (score 8):

It is a

> repetition

In fact those are

> Three repetitions, repetitions, repetitions.
>
> Two repetitions, repetitions.
>
> No repetition.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps

> A Guinea Pig. Several Guinea Pigs will thrive, whereas a single guinea pig will become lonely, and soon die.

Comment: That's why you take your guinea pig to a stud farm.

Answer (score 5):

Is it a

> [multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_birth)?

Because

> If you have triplets, you have three multiples.  If you have twins, you have two multiples.  But if you have a single child, you have no multiples.

Original answer, not correct by the precise definition (thanks @Will):

> clones

Because

> If you have three organisms with the same DNA, you have three clones.  But if you have one organism it is not a clone.

Comment: This is pedantic in the first place, but I'd argue if you have three you'd only have two.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you can't have one, then?

Comment: @paste: Depends how you interpret the riddle.  If you interpret it as `if you have X [babies], you have Y [multiples]` then it's consistent.

Comment: @MarkPeters Then the question would be "What are they?"

Comment: @paste: I don't understand your objection...if we're going by grammatical correctness, the question should be "what are they" even for the (probably correct) answer by TTT.  Multiple can be used in the singular, if that's what you're objecting to.  Saying "I am a multiple" is the generic way of saying "I am a twin".

Comment: @MarkPeters In TTT's case, his/her answer conforms to the format "If you have three X, you have three X" whereas yours is "If you have three X, you have three Y".

Comment: @paste: That's wonderful.  It's a riddle.  Riddles purposefully play on syntax and structure. There is no need to assume that they are the same.  My answer assumes a play on the word "have", because "having children" can mean giving birth in the first sense, and then possessing children in the second sense.  There's no need to pick apart answers for not being literal enough, when the riddle is tagged with "lateral thinking".

Answer (score 2):

It is a...

> Collection of things

Because...

> If you have three, you have three things, if you have two, you have two things, but if you have just one, you just own a thing, and it's not really a collection at all.

Answer (score 1):

It may be about physical sharing, and telling other people what you have.
If you have more than one unit of something you can inform your surroundings on this and share it with them.
On the other hand: if you have only one, telling others might induce envy and you may be better off not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking visually, it could be

> corners in the numerals 1, 2, 3 when drawn by hand. 3 has the upper right, middle left, and lower right; 2 has upper right and lower left; but 1 is usually a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is

> Cigarettes.

Reason

> You don't offer the last one.

Comment: The only sense that I can make of this is that it's backwards: if you have three, then you have two, and if you have two, then you have one, but if you have one, then you still / truly / absolutely / definitely have one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. I explain myself better: If someone ask you for a cigarette i tipically offer one unless there's only one remaining. In that case i keep it for myself.