# Riddle: When you have me

Tags: riddle, word

> Very often, you'll have me
>
> When you have me, you get multiple of me
>
> After getting me, you must make me
>
> And then all but one of me will disappear

Who or what am I?

Hint #1:

> The first me and the many of me that you get share the same name, but we aren't quite the same.

Hint #2:

> The one of me to stay will be one of the multiple you get, as referred to in line 2.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE

Comment: Another similar puzzle: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/32507/if-you-have-one-you-have-none

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you a:

> Choice?

Very often, you'll have me

> You'll have choices from time to time.

When you have me, you get multiple of me

> When you've a choice, it means you've multiple choices,

After getting me, you must make me

> you must make a choice

And then all but one of me will disappear

> Yup.

Comment: You've got it exactly! I was afraid that I didn't give enough information, but I'm glad to see that it came across. I thought of it after I saw a question on the math stack exchange noting the semantics behind a choice (when you have to pick between different options), and choices (the options from which you choose).

Comment: Some how the 'one of the multiple' in hint #2 gave me the idea.  Great riddle!

Answer (score 17):

Are you...

> Ikea furniture

---

Very often, you'll have me

> It's a popular store. People often get things there.

When you have me, you get multiple of me

> Everything comes in multiple pieces.

After getting me, you must make me

> You must assemble the pieces.

And then all but one of me will disappear

> This refers to that one piece left over when you're done that makes you question the safety of your new bunk bed.

Comment: This is really clever answer! Unfortunately, it's not the one I was looking for. I'll add a hint to differentiate this answer from the desired one.

Comment: :P I know it's wrong, but I had to do it.

Comment: [Lego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego) should also suffice :P

Comment: What a totally excellent answer. +1  Pure genius.

Answer (score 2):

I am

> a thought or idea

Very often, you'll have me

> ideas pop into your head all day long

When you have me, you get multiple of me

> One idea leads to another and another

After getting me, you must make me

> All of the ideas will coalesce into one idea

And then all but one of me will disappear

> Anything that doesn't fit with the coalesced idea is dropped

Comment: Nice try, but not the desired one.

Comment: @Kevin Long looks good to me. I know it's not correct, but I think it shows an issue with your question that it's too broad.

Answer (score 2):

I know the correct answer has already been posted, but I like this answer anyway:

Are you

> a cookie?

Very often, you'll have me

> I don't know about you, but I probably have more cookies than I need.

When you have me, you get multiple of me

> Cookies typically come in batches or packages of 12.

After getting me, you must make me

> You need to bake the dough before you have cookies.

And then all but one of me will dissapear

> That last cookie always sits around on the plate for far too long.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> a spermatozoon?

Very often, you'll have me

> if you find your partner sufficiently attractive and he is male

When you have me, you get multiple of me

> about a hundred million

After getting me, you must make me

> true before the modern era of contraception

And then all but one of me will disappear

> after nine months

Apologies

> trust I haven't pushed the bounds of good taste but it's just biology, folks

(I had actually edited this afterward to make a clarification for expected pedantry in which I suggested the term 'spermatazoon' be thought of in the context of "DNA contribution" and the term "make me" as in "make a recipe", which is fundamentally what DNA is.  The edit was pending review.)

Comment: Clever, though the "you must make me" part refers to the same "me", not making something out of "me".

Answer (score 1):

are you

> data

Very often, you'll have me

> lots of things generate data

When you have me, you get multiple of me

> data is always plural

After getting me, you must make me

> You use data to create other data, such as an average or std deviation or whatever statistic you need

And then all but one of me will disappear

> Now that you have an average or some other statistic, it encompasses all the other data and you don't need it anymore

Comment: Good answer, but not the one I'm looking for. I'll throw in another hint to differentiate.

Comment: @Kevin Long The question should be solveable without the hints. If I need the hints to solve it then I think it's not a good question.

Comment: data are* always plural. Sorry, had to do it!

Comment: i meant the word 'data' is always plural

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Number 1

Very often, you'll have me

> You have a lot of "one" things.

When you have me, you get multiple of me

> 1 is multiple of 1

After getting me, you must make me

> After getting one, you must make one

And then all but **one** of me will disappear

> "one"

Comment: Afraid not- the multiple part is clever, but I don't really see how the third hint plays into that explanation.